# Express routes with https

Tags: node.js, express, https

I want to make https express server and I have run in to the problem. Server runs without error. All http requests to server are routed to https so it is also fine. However I have folowing problems:

1. When I trying to connect to adders http://localhost "Home" should be displayed, but instead I get `Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403`
2. I can access any route if I try to connect like this https://localhost:8080 , but in this case I need to specify port 8080 and if I want server to listen to default https port 443 like this `https.createServer( options, app ).listen( 443 );` so I call https://localhost, I get same error `Access to localhost was denied You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403`

My server code:

```
const https = require( "https" ),
    fs = require( "fs" ),
    express = require( 'express' );

var key = fs.readFileSync( 'config/server.key' );
var cert = fs.readFileSync( 'config/server.crt' );
var ca = fs.readFileSync( 'config/server.crt' )

var options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert,
    ca: ca
};

const app = express();

app.get( '/hello', ( req, res ) => {
    res.send( "Hello" )
} )

app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.send( "home" )
} )

app.listen( 80 );

https.createServer( options, app ).listen( 8080 );
```

Comment: Your code does not show anything that routes http requests to https.  So, if that's actually happening with this code, you must have some other infrastructure installed that is doing that.  And, perhaps it is that same other infrastructure that is preventing you from using port 443.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I will check for that